# Aquaman's origins in Batman vs Superman

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, aquaman

Zack Snyder released a preview of what Aquaman looks like in "Batman vs. Superman: Dawn of Justice". On one of the comic sites I was looking at, someone was complaining because Aquaman's origin has been changed. According to them, in BvS Aquaman is the son of Poseidon instead of the human Arthur Curry.

Can anyone confirm this? Has anyone related to the film released information about Aquaman's origins? I've attempted to confirm on my own but haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: "Aquaman will be the son of Poseidon instead of human Arthur Curry". In Greek myths, most heroes were half-gods. So both options are not completely incompatible: in the DC Cinematic Universe, gods may have human children.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there was no effort to explain anything about Arthur Curry's origins in Batman Vs Superman (and he's the son of Thomas Curry, not Arthur - Arthur is his name), it was referenced in Justice League when he

> failed to stop Steppenwolf from stealing the mother box that had been protected by the Atlanteans for thousands of years.

Mera refers to his mother Atlanna, who was the Queen of Atlantis, and Arthur responds that he never knew her as she had abandoned him at birth.

EDIT: Confirmed as of Aquaman movie release in December 2018 that this is correct and he is the son of Atleantean Queen Atlanna and Thomas Curry, a lighthouse keeper.

I would say that this is sufficient to confirm that Arthur is NOT the son of Poseidon as posited in the question, but that his more common origin of human father Thomas Curry and Atlanna is applicable in the DCEU.